# Problem building has_many :through association - think I'm close

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails noob who has researched for weeks and tried all kinds of ways to do this.  **I'm currently trying to build an association from the edit view.**  I gave up trying to build it from the new view (preferred) because the object in question hadn't been created yet.  I'm now even using Formtastic, because I heard it "handles associations better"

In my question, I said that I'm close, because I'm able to manually create the association - by setting one end of the join with a controller-defined object rather than the object the user selects via the form.  The request parameters are being passed, I just can't seem to access them correctly.

Models:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :teams, :through => :bars_teams
  has_many :bars_teams, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars_teams

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :bars, :through => :bars_teams
  has_many :bars_teams, :dependent => :destroy

class BarsTeam < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :bar
  belongs_to :team
```

Bars Controller:

```
  def edit
    @bar = Bar.find(params[:id])
    @teams = Team.all
    @bars_team = @bar.bars_teams.build
    @title = "Edit bar"
  end

  def update
    @bar = Bar.find(params[:id])
    @team = @bars_team.team_id
    @bar.follow_team!(@team)
    if @bar.update_attributes(params[:bar])
      flash[:success] = "Bar updated."
      redirect_to @bar
    else
      @title = "Edit bar"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

from bar model - follow_team!:

```
  def follow_team!(team)
    bars_teams.create!(:team_id => team.id)
  end
```

**WHY I THINK I'M CLOSE**  (line from update above is wrong)

```
    @team = @bars_team.team_id
```

I can manually set that line, for example @team = Team.find(49).  That successfully creates the association from that bar to team #49.  I just can't seem to grab the team from the form...which by the way, here is the form:

Edit Form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for (@bar) do |form| %>
  <%= form.inputs :address, :city, :state, :zip_code, :phone_number, :website %>
    <%= form.semantic_fields_for @bars_team do |team| %>
      <%= team.input :team, :as => :select, :collection => @teams, :include_blank => false %>
      <%= team.input :bar_id, :as => :hidden %>
    <% end %>
  <%= form.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

If anyone is interested, here is the request parameters, showing that the information is getting passed, yet I still don't know how to access the team correctly:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"ECOBrnXsgMA5k2XKIiaZ7iguaIlUtj3pSHREZ683HKw=",
 "bar"=>{"address"=>"",
 "city"=>"",
 "state"=>"",
 "zip_code"=>"",
 "phone_number"=>"",
 "website"=>"",
 "bars_team"=>{"team_id"=>"20",
 "bar_id"=>"46"}},
 "commit"=>"Update Bar",
 "id"=>"46"}
```

Super long story short, how do I access the team from the form to set the association?

Bonus to anyone who can help with my original problem of not being able to create the association from the new view.  Essentially creating a new bar, and immediately assigning a team to it upon creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
@team = @bars_team.team_id
```

to

```
@team = Team.find(params[:bar][:bars_team][:team_id])
```

The whole arrangement is unnecessarily complex though.

Comment: This worked for the question asked.  I will, however, look into both answers more thoroughly - including this one regarding the complexity, and @jimworms response about not even needing to do it the way I have it set up.  I hope, as I learn more, I will be able to determine these things ahead of time.  Thank you for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the case to use `fields_for` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Try getting rid of all the @bars_team stuff and just do this in your form:

```
<%= form.input :teams, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => @teams %>
```

Caution: I've never used formtastic myself, but this is what I got after reading the docs.

Comment: Thank you for this response, I will try a solution like this as well - even though the other answer worked for my 'as-built' needs.  Rebuilding will be my second priority, and may include something along this line.  Thanks!